# minecraft wont take keyboard input

Tags: java, 13.10, minecraft

After upgrading to 13.10 FTB(minecraft) wont take keyboard input after login in. I can click the buttons but it will not let me type in a address on multiplayer, or copy/paste with mouse.

Since upgrading I cannot run the other mod packs either, only the one I had installed from 13.04.

I get this when running a new modpack:

```
2013-10-28 15:14:52 [INFO] [STDERR] Exception in thread "Minecraft main thread" 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 2013-10-28 15:14:52 [INFO] [STDERR] at 
net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:355) 2013-10-28 15:14:52 
[INFO] [STDERR] at net.minecraft.client.MinecraftAppletImpl.func_71384_a(SourceFile:56) 
2013-10-28 15:14:52 [INFO] [STDERR] at 
net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:733) 2013-10-28 15:14:52 [INFO] 
[STDERR] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) 2013-10-28 15:14:52 [INFO] [STDERR] 
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 2013-10-28 15:14:52 [INFO] 
[STDERR] at org.lwjgl.opengl.XRandR$Screen.<init>(XRandR.java:234) 2013-10-28 15:14:52 
[INFO] [STDERR] at org.lwjgl.opengl.XRandR$Screen.<init>(XRandR.java:196) 2013-10-28 
15:14:52 [INFO] [STDERR] at org.lwjgl.opengl.XRandR.populate(XRandR.java:87) 2013-10-28 
15:14:52 [INFO] [STDERR] at org.lwjgl.opengl.XRandR.access$100(XRandR.java:52) 2013-10-28
15:14:52 [INFO] [STDERR] at org.lwjgl.opengl.XRandR$1.run(XRandR.java:110) 2013-10-28 
15:14:52 [INFO] [STDERR] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
2013-10-28 15:14:52 [INFO] [STDERR] at 
org.lwjgl.opengl.XRandR.getConfiguration(XRandR.java:108) 2013-10-28 15:14:52 [INFO] 
[STDERR] at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.init(LinuxDisplay.java:618) 2013-10-28 15:14:52 
[INFO] [STDERR] at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135) 2013-10-28 
15:14:52 [INFO] [STDERR] ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your lwjgl.

1)Download LWJLG 2.9.0 
2)extract the lwjgl.jar to .minecraft/bin
3)extract the files in lwjgl/natives/linux to .minecraft/bin/natives

your .minecraft is your home folder (show hidden files with crtl + h)

if you can't find it then, search the home folder and click it from there (after showing hidden)

good luck